# Spotify microphone access not listed in Security & Privacy

Tags: macos, big-sur, spotify

When I open lid after sleep  my security tool warns me that new process is asking for microphone access. However, there is no log in the macOS Security & Privacy.
The helper tool I use is caller "OVERSIGHT" (from malware researcher) and I have been using it for the past 3 years without any issue.

Is there a loophole in the microphone access?

Using macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 I haven't updated the tool. Spotify does upgrades on background.

[image]